# Change loopback default model User to Member

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

I just don't want to use the name "User", I want it to be "Member"

//// this is for bypassing stackoverflow qualiy control

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the built-in model User:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html

```
server/models/Member.json

{
  "name": "Member",
  "base": "User",
...  
}
```